# MongoDb data modelling, one large collection VS multiple smaller collections

Tags: database, mongodb, data-structures, data-modeling, mongodb-atlas

I have trouble deciding what data model structure i should have on my mongodb data. I have read that some says that one large collection is the best option, and some say that multiple smaller collection is the best option.

I have "Users" which will be stored in a collection.

The options i have looked at is:

1.

```
Users (the collection):
  _id (what the documents include)
  name
  ...

Posts:
  _id
  user_id
  title
  body
```

To find all posts by the user I will query .collection("Posts").find({user_id: "123test"})

2.

```
Users:
  _id
  name
  ...

(user1)Posts:
  _id
  title
  body

(user2)Posts:
  _id
  title
  body

(user3)Posts:
  _id
  title
  body

...
```

To find all posts by the user I will query .collection(user + "Posts").find({})

The users and Posts will be growing constantly and i want something good for large amount of data. A user might have 1000-10000 Posts for example.
And there might be around 100 users at the end.
That will equal 10 000 000 Posts.
I will also be using multiple filters with multiple indexes on the Posts collection(s).

Im using Mongodb atlas serverless so what option is the most performant and cheapest?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best solution here would be to go with the first approach, avoiding having abnormally bloated documents in the `Users` collection, on the lines of [The Subset Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern). The reason being optimal usage of the [Working Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-working-set), which is stored in the RAM. Whenever you fire a query, it first tries to get resolved from the RAM, and if it is unable to, it goes to the disk to fetch data, thereby increasing latency.

Thus, if you have larger documents, the storage engine will be able to accommodate lesser number of those in the working set stored in RAM, vs., if you have smaller documents, it will be able to accommodate more number of documents, thereby increasing the probability of your queries getting resolved from the RAM itself, and not having to travel to disk or only for a limited set of data.

Apart from this, maintainability & scalability is also better when you store `Posts` in a separate collection with a field called `user_id`, as you've shown in the first example. Also, if there's a use case wherein you have to show a user's top 10 posts or something like that, then you can store a `posts` field of type `Array<Posts>`, [making sure it is a bounded array with limited items, and not unbounded](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but a actually went with the database-per-tenent approach. Just because I care about security and want to keep data separated from other users